# Heroku pg:pull stalls out on tiny database?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

```
$ heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL mylocaldb2 --app afternoon-sunday-4103                                          
heroku-cli: Pulling postgresql-globular-1902 ---> mylocaldb2
```

it then stalls out at

```
pg_dump: dumping contents of table photos
```

I ran it three times now, including over night. This is not a large database.

```
$ heroku pg:info 

Tables: 32 
Rows: 1775 
Data Size: 9.9 MB

$ heroku pg:psql 

psql (9.4.10, server 9.4.9)
```

How do I troubleshoot? I am trying to pull my production database to my local database. My local databases are all empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get this to work and just used capture/download instead.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export